# Loop through a range of selected cells and use text to column to split 1 cell across 4 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a range of selected cells to split the text inside the cell across 3 or 4 columns from the activeCell.

This is a screen shot of the Excel file with the two examples, the top data is how it should be and after is the raw data that I need to split

I have the below code. If I take cell by cell it does the job but I need it to go through each cell and split the text in the range that I select also I would need a way to stop executing the code is the cell is empty and if the process was done before or it's not matching with any of the string length to continue the loop.

I don't know if the ElseIf was the right way to go. I was thinking to use a case statement instead to check and see which one of the split methods to use for each cell. The first example is easy but the second one is the tricky bit as when copying from Outlook you get some space and 1/ that I want to skip and not import in the text to column output. That is why for each cell I check the length of characters to determine the right split solution to use.

```
Sub splitStyleFabricColourSize()

Dim cellRow As Range
Dim mergedCells As Range
Dim cellInfo As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set mergedCells = Selection

On Error Resume Next

For Each cellRow In mergedCells.Cells
cellRow.Select

cellInfo = ActiveCell.Characters.Count
Debug.Print cellInfo

If cellInfo = 15 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 17 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, 9), Array(13, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 18 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(8, 1), Array(13, 9), Array(14, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 22 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, 9), Array(13, 1), _
        Array(17, 9), Array(20, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 23 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, 9), Array(13, 1), _
        Array(17, 9), Array(21, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 24 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, _
        9), Array(13, 1), Array(17, 9), Array(22, 1))


ElseIf cellInfo = 25 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array( _
        12, 9), Array(13, 1), Array(17, 9), Array(23, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 26 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array( _
        12, 9), Array(13, 1), Array(17, 9), Array(22, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 27 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(8, 1), Array( _
        13, 9), Array(14, 1), Array(18, 9), Array(23, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 29 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(8, 1), Array(13, _
        9), Array(14, 1), Array(18, 9), Array(25, 1))

ElseIf cellInfo = 52 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, 9), Array(13, 1), _
        Array(17, 9), Array(20, 1), Array(42, 9))

End If

Next cellRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'm stuck at a problem and wondering if you can help me. The number of character is 24 for both examples but the way they are below is different because of the "-" symbol so the text to column will pick it up differently. How would I go about solving this problem because the code below is different where you start separating the columns length. I did not anticipate this problem so.the code has a weakness in the end if the character count of the text is the same but different formatting then this will not work well. Is there a way to record a pattern like first string character in column 1 should have 6 digits and then second column should have 5 characters third column should have 4 digits and forth column should have 4 characters or more because clearly the array here is not helping me if the format that I receive from emails changes.

```
ElseIf cellInfo = 24 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array(12, _
        9), Array(13, 1), Array(17, 9), Array(22, 1))
​
ElseIf cellInfo = 24 Then
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
        , OtherChar:="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9), Array(7, 1), Array( _
        12, 9), Array(14, 1), Array(18, 9), Array(20, 1))
```

Comment: should _"454053S17371000"_ and  _"443582 W0yg0 1000 1/41"_ be examples of a "before" and after" scenario? If so, they don't match at all. You may want to add some link to screenshots of _real_ "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: I want to split 454053S17371000 in 3 columns and 443582 W0yg0 1000 1/41 in 4 columns so they are not the same it's just different data.

Comment: I've solved my problem with looping through the selected range. I needed in the for each loop to include cellRow.Select to actually select each cell and split the text in 3 or 4 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming those are spaces, right.

```
Sub TryThis()

'SPLIT INTO COLUMNS
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
splitVals = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, " ")
totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals

End Sub
```

[image]

This will split all selected cells (all cells in a selected range)..

```
Sub SplitCells()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng

splitVals = Split(Rng.Value, " ")
    totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
    Range(Cells(Rng.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(Rng.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
Next
End Sub
```

Finally, and I'm not totally sure this is relevant, but based on your last comment, it sounds like you need the LEN function and the FIND function.
Description

The Microsoft Excel LEN function returns the length of the specified string.

The LEN function is a built-in function in Excel that is categorized as a String/Text Function. It can be used as a worksheet function (WS) and a VBA function (VBA) in Excel. As a worksheet function, the LEN function can be entered as part of a formula in a cell of a worksheet. As a VBA function, you can use this function in macro code that is entered through the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor.
Syntax

The syntax for the LEN function in Microsoft Excel is:

```
LEN( text )
```

Description

The Microsoft Excel FIND function returns the location of a substring in a string. The search is case-sensitive.

The FIND function is a built-in function in Excel that is categorized as a String/Text Function. It can be used as a worksheet function (WS) in Excel. As a worksheet function, the FIND function can be entered as part of a formula in a cell of a worksheet.
Syntax

The syntax for the FIND function in Microsoft Excel is:

```
FIND( substring, string, [start_position] )
```

Parameters or Arguments

substring
    The substring that you want to find.
string
    The string to search within.
start_position
    Optional. It is the position in string where the search will start. The first position is 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help you have a different approach than me but from your example above it should override from cell A to D so the big string that is in A will start from A going to D and without the 1/ i will only need the size. But then this approach doesn't solve me this scenario 470104S17849504 splitting 3 columns the character count should be the same for each column in your example less the size. More than that this will need to be on the selection range that i do not hard coded in specific cells.

Comment: I just updated my original answer to accommodate all selected cells.  I don't understand the very first part.  You say you want to split this: 454053S17371000

What is the criteria for splitting that?  In my example I'm splitting the contents of the cell out by spaces.  I don't seen any logical way to split your cell into 3 separate columns.

Comment: I use the text to columns to split. I did it by recording the macro and then replicate the code to match my needs.

Comment: What criteria are you using to split the single cell into multiple columns?

Comment: I use the below code 'If cellInfo = 15 Then

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1))'  so this is the mothod i use to separate it will have a total count of 15 characters.

Comment: I wouldn't have guess that...OK, loop through cells in a range.  This is a VERY simple solution.  You can obviously make the range dynamic, and you can add a condition to test for blanks, then do the last thing I suggested, ELSE, do the thing you posted directly above.

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
For Each cell In rng
   ' If condition Then
   ' MyCode
   ' Else
   ' YourCode 
Next cell

Comment: is there a better way to write it as the data will always be the same in the sense that for example 454053S17371000 ; 454053 S1737 1000 ; 454053S17371000 -1/34; 454053 S1737 1000 1/34 all these data will be the same length as follows first column will be exactly 6 characters long second column will be exactly 5 characters long third column will be exactly 4 characters long and the forth column the size 1/34 i actually need only the size so will be exactly 2 characters so will be 34. Will this be possible to write differently as my method has a bug when the format is different?

Comment: I just updated my original code with all the checks i need to do to split the text properly and i though i covered everything but apparently the format will change and what i mean by that maybe there will be extra space and will not fall in any condition and then the "-" will differ. So will there be a way to tell excel how many characters needs to be in the 4 cells as this is the format that needs to go into the 4 cells. I need something to force the split regardless of the format i think that will solve all the issues that i am having with this file. Any help will be appreciated.